# Disable HTML TextField Drop down suggestion box

Tags: browser, autocomplete, settings

Ok so you know when type something the textfield such as "test" and then go back and it will suggest "test" when you type in "t"? How do I disable the textfield from doign that drop down suggestion box?

If at all, possible - thanks.

Comment: It's in your browser settings. Firefox is Options -> Advanced -> General, have you tried browsing through them all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use autocomplete="off" as in Google homepage

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature of the browser, not of your HTML.  If you want your browser to stop doing that, turn off "Auto Suggest" or "Auto Complete" or whatever the feature is called in your particular browser.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's a function of the browser, and the way to turn it off would vary.  It's not something I think you'd be able to do in code, though.

I just checked IE8 and you can go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Content, click the Settings button under AutoComplete, and then untick the Forms box.